# HTTPS on a custom port other than 80 and 443

Tags: apache, https, port, lets-encrypt, redash

I have a website, let's say example.com (Apache, Ubuntu 16.04)

I've installed Letsencrypt and the site is accessible via HTTPS.

On the same server, I have Redash running and that is accessible via port 90. So, to access Redash, I go to example.com:90

The problem is that Redash is not accessible via HTTPS.

How to make port 90 accessible via HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

Best way would be to use a Nginx proxy for handling the SSL certificate. 
You can setup the Nginx proxy with your ssl certificate at port 443 to serve your Redash port 90 on the url: https://example.com/redash. 
Nginx will catch this request at your SSL encrypted port 443 and serve what ever your port 90 response.